# If I rotate a metallic plate with a threshold frequency of f0 around a light source with a frequency of f0, would the plate eject electrons?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

The concept is to construct an analog of the Kundig experiment, but for the photoelectric effect:

[Kundig Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment#M%C3%B6ssbauer_rotor_experiments)

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Since we know that  hv=hv0 +KEmax 
Now this frequency can only overcome force of attraction between atoms , it will also eject electrons ,but electrons will not move since all energy get wasted in overcoming force of attraction